# Compress image file in android application

Tags: php, android, image, file, image-compression

I'm trying to create an application that uploads an image from a device to a remote server Everything is working fine but I need to compress the file's size from few MBs to a few tens or hundreds KBs. I did a little research but everywhere I looked it was about compressing bitmaps and in my code I have a File and FileInputStream. This is my java code for sending the image to the server:

```
public class ImageUpload {

    private String filePath;
    private String picName;

    public ImageUpload(int num, String path) {
        filePath = path;
        picName = "Pic" + num + ".jpg";
        insertIntoServer();
    }

    public void insertIntoServer() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                uploadFile();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public int uploadFile() {
        final String upLoadServerUri = "http://.../UploadToServer.php";
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        DataOutputStream dos;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File sourceFile = new File(filePath);
        int serverResponseCode = 0;

        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist : " + filePath);
            return 0;
        } else {
            try {
                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);

                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", picName);

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\"" + picName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // create a buffer of  maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

                if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
                    // Read response
                    final StringBuilder responseSB = new StringBuilder();
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

                    String line;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                        responseSB.append(line);

                    // Close streams
                    br.close();
                }
                //close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            return serverResponseCode;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my PHP file that gets the file and saves them on the server:

```
<?php

   $file_path = "../files/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

What do I need to change in my php file or my java file?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I added this row: "BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileInputStream).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 25, dos);" and now nothing happened. The application didn't fall but the picture wasn't uploaded. I added the row after this row "dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());", after all the "conn" rows. Maybe I should place it anywhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this row:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileInputStream).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 15, dos);
```

After this row:

```
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
```

And now the image uploads with smaller size.